# FIRST and FOLLOW sets calculator in Haskell

Tags: beginner, parsing, haskell, grammar

I found myself wanting to brush up on some notions about parsers and grammars *and*, at the same time, to exercise my Haskell - I am a Haskell newbie; moreover, I haven't touched the language at all in a couple months.

You can find the complete result [here](https://github.com/tobiatesan/first-follow-calculator/tree/028e1ea31a405b7f59f19be7696f22e99a62d001), and, separated by hrs and without the module boilerplate, pasted below.

I'm not exactly happy with it.

It seems somewhat dirty and convoluted for something that is stated so simply in a few lines of English in the reference textbook - (meaning, [the (Purple) Dragon Book](https://books.google.it/books?id=dIU_AQAAIAAJ)).

I am also noticing a complete lack of typically functional constructs - function composition, curried functions, etc - which *might* be a code smell.

On the other hand, after spending a couple nights on it, I can't seem to find any more opportunity for improvement: I'm stuck.

Any suggestions both in the small and in the large scale are appreciated.

```
---------------------------------
-- Datatypes and utilities
---------------------------------

data Terminal = T String | Dollar | Epsilon deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
data Nonterminal = NT String | Start String deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

type Symbol = (Either Nonterminal Terminal)

data Production = Prod {left_hand :: Nonterminal, right_hand :: [Symbol]} deriving (Show, Eq)
data Grammar = Grammar [Production] deriving (Show)

allTerminalsInGrammar :: Grammar -> Set Terminal
allTerminalsInGrammar (Grammar []) = Data.Set.empty
allTerminalsInGrammar (Grammar (prod:prods)) =
  (
    Data.Set.union
    (allTerminalsInGrammar (Grammar prods))
    (Data.Set.fromList $ onlyTerminals (right_hand prod))
    )
  where onlyTerminals a = rights a

allNonterminalsInGrammar :: Grammar -> Set Nonterminal
allNonterminalsInGrammar (Grammar []) = Data.Set.empty
allNonterminalsInGrammar (Grammar (prod:prods)) =
  (
    Data.Set.union
    (allNonterminalsInGrammar (Grammar prods))
    (Data.Set.singleton (left_hand prod))
    )

type FirstSet = (Set Terminal)
type FollowSet = (Set Terminal)
data FirstMap = FirstMap (Data.Map.Map Nonterminal (Set Terminal)) deriving (Show, Eq)
-- A FirstMap maps a symbol to its FirstSet

data FollowMap = FollowMap (Data.Map.Map Nonterminal (Set Terminal)) deriving (Show, Eq)
-- A FollowMap maps a symbol to its FollowSet

getFirstSetFor :: Nonterminal -> FirstMap -> FirstSet
getFirstSetFor nonterminal (FirstMap firstmap) =
  f $ Data.Map.lookup nonterminal firstmap
  where
    f Nothing = Data.Set.empty
    f (Just set) = set

getFollowSetFor :: Nonterminal -> FollowMap -> FollowSet
getFollowSetFor nonterminal (FollowMap firstmap) =
  f $ Data.Map.lookup nonterminal firstmap
  where
    f Nothing = Data.Set.empty
    f (Just set) = set

mergeSetIntoFirstMap :: FirstMap -> Nonterminal -> Set Terminal -> FirstMap
mergeSetIntoFirstMap (FirstMap map) nt t = FirstMap (insertWith (Data.Set.union) nt t map)

mergeSetIntoFollowMap :: FollowMap -> Nonterminal -> Set Terminal -> FollowMap
mergeSetIntoFollowMap (FollowMap map) nt t = FollowMap (insertWith (Data.Set.union) nt t map)

---------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
fixpoint :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
fixpoint f x = let x' = f x in if x == x' then x else fixpoint f x'
```

---

```
----------------------------------------------------
-- FIRST⁰ gives ∅ to each nonterminal;
--
-- Then repeat:
--
-- If X is a terminal then FIRST(X) = {X}
-- If X is a nonterminal
--   If X -> ε is a production then add ε to FIRST(X)
--   If X->Y₁ Y₂ ... Yk for some k >= 1
--     If ε is in FIRST⁻¹(Yⱼ) for ALL j= 1...k add ε
--     If ε is in FIRST⁻¹(Yᵢ) for ALL i= 1...l < k
--                   then add FIRST(Yₗ₊1)
--
-- Stop when nothing can be added (i.e.: find a fixpoint)


first :: Grammar -> FirstMap
first grammar = (fixpoint  (firsti grammar) (first0 grammar))
  where
    --------------------------------------------------------
    first0 :: Grammar -> FirstMap
    first0 grammar = FirstMap $
      (Data.Map.fromList $ (fmap defaults) $ Data.Set.toList (allNonterminalsInGrammar grammar))
      where
        defaults nt = (nt, (Data.Set.empty))
    --------------------------------------------------------
    firsti :: Grammar -> FirstMap -> FirstMap
    firsti (Grammar []) fMinus1 = fMinus1
    firsti (Grammar (prod:prods)) fMinus1 =
      (
        mergeSetIntoFirstMap                  -- Add to the FIRST_(i-1) set,
        (firsti (Grammar prods) fMinus1)      -- (computed from the remaining productions)
        (left_hand prod)                      -- for the symbol on the LHS of the current production prod,
        (terminalsForRHS prod)                -- the terminals obtained by applying the rules on the current production prod
      )
      where   
        --
        terminalsForRHS :: Production -> Set Terminal
        terminalsForRHS (Prod _ []) = (Data.Set.singleton Epsilon)
        --   If X -> ε is a production then add ε to FIRST(X)        
        terminalsForRHS (Prod _ [(Right Epsilon)]) = (Data.Set.singleton Epsilon)
        terminalsForRHS (Prod x (yj:ys)) =
          case yj of
            -- If X is a terminal then FIRST(X) = {X}     
            Right terminal    -> Data.Set.singleton terminal
            -- Otherwise...
            Left  nonterminal -> if   (Data.Set.member Epsilon first_iminus1)
                                 then (Data.Set.union
                                       (terminalsForYj)
                                       (terminalsForRHS (Prod x ys)))
                                 else  (terminalsForYj)  
              where
                first_iminus1 = getFirstSetFor nonterminal fMinus1

                terminalsForYj = (Data.Set.delete Epsilon first_iminus1)
            --     If ε is in FIRST⁻¹(Yᵢ) for ALL i= 1...l < k
            --                   then add FIRST(Yₗ₊1)
            --     --> guaranteed because we add FIRST(Yₗ₊1) and we
            --         continue adding terminalsRHS for the
            --         remainder of the production only if ε is in FIRST⁻¹

            --     If ε is in FIRST⁻¹(Yⱼ) for ALL j= 1...k add ε
            --     --> guaranteed because we continue adding terminalsRHS for the
            --         remainder of the production only if ε is in FIRST⁻¹
            --         eventually adding terminalsForRHS (Prod _ []) = (Data.Set.singleton Epsilon)
```

---

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- We can compute FIRST for any string X₁X₂...Xₙ as follows.
-- Add to FIRST(X₁X₂... Xₙ) all non-ε symbols of FIRST(X₁).
-- Also add the non-ε symbols of FIRST(X₂), if ε is in FIRST(X₁);
-- and so on.
-- Finally, add ε to FIRST(X₁X₂ . . Xₙ) if, for all i, ε is in FIRST(Xᵢ)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
firstForWord :: [Symbol] -> FirstMap -> FirstSet
firstForWord [(Left nt)] first = getFirstSetFor nt first -- If Epsilon in first don't remove
firstForWord [(Right t)] first = (Data.Set.singleton t)
firstForWord ((Left nt):ss) first =
  if (Data.Set.member
      Epsilon
      (getFirstSetFor nt first)
     )
  then (Data.Set.union
        firstMinusEpsilon
        (firstForWord ss first)
       )
  else firstMinusEpsilon
       where firstMinusEpsilon = (Data.Set.delete
                                  Epsilon
                                  (getFirstSetFor nt first)
                                 )
```

---

```
----------------------------------------------------
-- FOLLOW⁰ gives $ to FOLLOW(S) and {} to everything else;
--
-- Then repeat:
--
-- If there is a production A -> w₁Bw₂ ,
--   then everything in FIRST(w₂) except ε is in FOLLOW(B)
--   If where FIRST(w₂) contains Epsilon,
--   then everything in FOLLOW (A) is also in FOLLOW (B).
-- If there is a production A -> w₁B,
--   then everything in FOLLOW (A) is in FOLLOW (B).
--
-- Stop when nothing can be added (i.e. find a fixpoint)
-----------------------------------------------------

follow :: Grammar -> FollowMap
follow grammar = (fixpoint (followi grammar (first grammar)) (follow0 grammar))
  where
    --------------------------------------------------------
    follow0 :: Grammar -> FollowMap
    follow0 grammar = FollowMap $
      (Data.Map.fromList $ (fmap defaults) $ Data.Set.toList (allNonterminalsInGrammar grammar))
      where
        defaults nt@(NT _) = (nt, (Data.Set.empty))
        defaults nt@(Start _) = (nt, (Data.Set.singleton Dollar))
    --------------------------------------------------------
    followi :: Grammar -> FirstMap -> FollowMap -> FollowMap
    followi (Grammar [])  _ fMinus1 = fMinus1
    followi (Grammar (prod:prods)) firstMapForG fMinus1 =
      (mergeTerminalsFromProd   -- Add the terminals obtained by applying the rules on the current production
       prod
       (followi            -- 
        (Grammar prods)    --
        firstMapForG       -- to the FOLLOW sets obtained from the remaining productions
        fMinus1            --
       )
      )
      where
        mergeTerminalsFromProd :: Production -> FollowMap -> FollowMap
        mergeTerminalsFromProd (Prod l (s:ss)) = (mergeTerminalsFromProd' l [] s ss)
        mergeTerminalsFromProd' :: Nonterminal -> [Symbol] -> Symbol -> [Symbol] -> FollowMap -> FollowMap
        -- If there is a production A -> w₁Bw₂ ,
        mergeTerminalsFromProd' a w1 nt@(Left b) w2@(w21:w2s) fMinus1 = (mergeSetIntoFollowMap
                                                                         (mergeTerminalsFromProd' a (w1 ++ [nt]) w21 w2s fMinus1)
                                                                         b
                                                                         newTerminals
                                                                        )
          where
              --  everything in FIRST(w₂) except ε is in FOLLOW(B)
              firstW2MinusEpsilon = (Data.Set.delete Epsilon (firstForWord w2 firstMapForG))
              newTerminals = if (Data.Set.member Epsilon (firstForWord w2 firstMapForG))
                                --   If where FIRST(w₂) contains Epsilon,
                                --   then everything in FOLLOW (A) is also in FOLLOW (B).
                             then (Data.Set.union (getFollowSetFor a fMinus1) firstW2MinusEpsilon)
                             else (firstForWord w2 firstMapForG)
        -- If there is a production A -> w₁B, then everything in FOLLOW (A) is in FOLLOW (B).
        mergeTerminalsFromProd' a w1 (Left b) [] fMinus1 = (mergeSetIntoFollowMap
                                                            fMinus1
                                                            b
                                                            (getFollowSetFor a fMinus1)
                                                           )
        -- We don't have to insert anything for terminals; i.e. there are no rules
        -- for A -> w₁Tw₂ where T is terminal; if we are at the end of the production we're done
        mergeTerminalsFromProd' a _ (Right _) [] fMinus1 = fMinus1
        -- Otherwise just recurse
        mergeTerminalsFromProd' a w1 (Right t) (w2:w2s) fMinus1 = (mergeTerminalsFromProd' a (w1 ++ [(Right t)]) w2 w2s fMinus1)
```

---

```
main = let
  -- Example from dragon book
  dragon_gram = Grammar [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8] where
    p1 = Prod {left_hand = (Start "E"),   right_hand = [Left  (NT "T"),   Left (NT "E'")]}
    p2 = Prod {left_hand = (NT "E'"),  right_hand = [Right (T "+"),    Left (NT "T"),    Left (NT "E'")]}
    p3 = Prod {left_hand = (NT "E'"),  right_hand = [Right Epsilon]}
    p4 = Prod {left_hand = (NT "T"),   right_hand = [Left  (NT "F"),   Left (NT "T'")]}
    p5 = Prod {left_hand = (NT "T'"),  right_hand = [Right (T "*"),    Left (NT "F"),    Left (NT "T'")]}
    p6 = Prod {left_hand = (NT "T'"),  right_hand = [Right Epsilon]}
    p7 = Prod {left_hand = (NT "F"),   right_hand = [Right (T "("),    Left (Start "E"),    Right (T ")")]}
    p8 = Prod {left_hand = (NT "F"),   right_hand = [Right (T "id")]}
  in do
  putStrLn "EXAMPLE GRAMMAR: "
  print (dragon_gram)
  putStrLn "FIRST(G) = "
  print (first dragon_gram)
  putStrLn "FOLLOW(G) = "
  print (follow dragon_gram)
```

Answer (score 2):

I refactored for a while, largely replacing recursion with combinators. I think all these type aliases are unnecessary, I probably would have removed them if I had finished this. You didnt actually use the LHS in `terminalsForRHS`, except to pass it into recursive calls, so I took it out.

```
module First where
import Data.Map
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Either
import Data.Set
import Control.Arrow

---------------------------------
-- Datatypes and utilities
---------------------------------

data Terminal = T String | Dollar | Epsilon deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
data Nonterminal = NT String | Start String deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

type Symbol = Either Nonterminal Terminal

type Production = (Nonterminal, Symbol)
type Grammar = [Production]

allTerminalsInGrammar :: Grammar -> Set Terminal
allTerminalsInGrammar = foldMap $ Data.Set.fromList . rights . snd

allNonterminalsInGrammar :: Grammar -> Set Nonterminal
allNonterminalsInGrammar = Data.Set.fromList . map fst

type FFSet = Set Terminal
type FFMap = Data.Map.Map Nonterminal FFSet
-- A First/FollowMap maps a symbol to its First/FollowSet

getSetFor :: Nonterminal -> FFMap -> FFSet
getSetFor nt = fold . Data.Map.lookup nt

mergeSetIntoFFMap :: Nonterminal -> Set Terminal -> FFMap -> FFMap
mergeSetIntoFFMap = insertWith Data.Set.union

---------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------
-- Main program
-----------------------

fixpoint :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
fixpoint f x = let x' = f x in if x == x' then x else fixpoint f x'

----------------------------------------------------
-- FIRST⁰ gives ∅ to each nonterminal;
--
-- Then repeat:
--
-- If X is a terminal then FIRST(X) = {X}
-- If X is a nonterminal
--   If X -> ε is a production then add ε to FIRST(X)
--   If X->Y₁ Y₂ ... Yk for some k >= 1
--     If ε is in FIRST⁻¹(Yⱼ) for ALL j= 1...k add ε
--     If ε is in FIRST⁻¹(Yᵢ) for ALL i= 1...l < k
--                   then add FIRST(Yₗ₊1)
--
-- Stop when nothing can be added (i.e.: find a fixpoint)
----------------------------------------------------                                                      

first :: Grammar -> FirstMap
first grammar = fixpoint (`firsti` grammar) Data.Map.empty where
  firsti :: FirstMap -> Grammar -> FirstMap
  firsti fMinus1 = fromListWith Data.Set.union . (map . right)
    -- The terminals obtained by applying the rules on the current production prod
    (foldr terminalsForRHS $ Data.Set.singleton Epsilon) where
    terminalsForRHS :: Symbol -> Set Terminal -> Set Terminal
    -- If X is a terminal then FIRST(X) = {X}
    terminalsForRHS (Right terminal) _ = Data.Set.singleton terminal
    terminalsForRHS (Left nonterminal) foo = Data.Set.union
      (  Data.Set.delete Epsilon first_iminus1)
      if Data.Set.member Epsilon first_iminus1
        then foo
        else Data.Set.empty 
      where
        first_iminus1 = getSetFor nonterminal fMinus1
    --     If ε is in FIRST⁻¹(Yᵢ) for ALL i= 1...l < k
    --                   then add FIRST(Yₗ₊1)
    --     --> guaranteed because we add FIRST(Yₗ₊1) and we
    --         continue adding terminalsRHS for the
    --         remainder of the production only if ε is in FIRST⁻¹

    --     If ε is in FIRST⁻¹(Yⱼ) for ALL j= 1...k add ε
    --     --> guaranteed because we continue adding terminalsRHS for the
    --         remainder of the production only if ε is in FIRST⁻¹
    --         eventually adding terminalsForRHS (Prod _ []) = Data.Set.singleton Epsilon)                         

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- We can compute FIRST for any string X₁X₂...Xₙ as follows.
-- Add to FIRST(X₁X₂... Xₙ) all non-ε symbols of FIRST(X₁).
-- Also add the non-ε symbols of FIRST(X₂), if ε is in FIRST(X₁);
-- and so on.
-- Finally, add ε to FIRST(X₁X₂ . . Xₙ) if, for all i, ε is in FIRST(Xᵢ)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
firstForWord :: [Symbol] -> FFMap -> FFSet
firstForWord [Left nt] first = getSetFor nt first -- If Epsilon in first don't remove
firstForWord [Right t] first = Data.Set.singleton t
firstForWord (Left nt:ss) first = Data.Set.union 
  (  Data.Set.delete Epsilon $ getSetFor nt first)
  if Data.Set.member Epsilon $ getSetFor nt first
    then firstForWord ss first
    else Data.Set.empty
```

Edit:

```
firstForWord :: FFMap -> [Symbol] -> FFSet
firstForWord first = unsnoc >>> \(Just (lefts, last)) ->
  foldr foo (either (`getSetFor` first) Data.Set.singleton) lefts where
    foo (Left nt) bar = Data.Set.union 
      (  Data.Set.delete Epsilon $ getSetFor nt first)
      if Data.Set.member Epsilon $ getSetFor nt first
        then bar
        else Data.Set.empty
```

And then, if you don't mind making it more defined, make this and the above similar snippet use the same first argument to foldr.

Comment: Thank you *a lot*, this is really a great help as it is. I had a few "d'oh" moments while reading it, I expect I'll have more when altering my code to reflect yours.

Just one thing, though: why did you merge `FirstSet` and `FollowSet` into `FFSet`? I originally kept them separate on purpose, to make sure not to use a FirstSet as a FollowSet or viceversa inside some nested call. Is that a bad Java-ism? Does Haskell provide a better way to avoid that? Thank you.

Comment: I find that these wrappers, that everyone invents anew, make it harder to see patterns that can be replaced by a combinator from some library that already did the heavy lifting. Mixing up which goes where shouldn't be much of a problem once the code has been reduced sufficiently. Repost if you find many reductions, I might see more on another pass.